# Delete rows X to Y in on a specific Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am writing a VBScript which opens an Excel file, deletes rows `X` to `Y`from a specific Sheet then saves and closes the file. The opening and closing part I have down however deleting part is what I am struggling with.  `X` and `Y` are fixed, say rows 6 to 10.

```
Set objExcel=CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = True

Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.open("FILE_ADDRESS")

Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

ws.Rows(2).Delete

wb.Save
wb.Close

objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: Please show your code you have so far. Have you tried anything to delete the rows yet?

Comment: Yeah I used the one which is shown above, but it does not seem to work. I also used another function yesterday, which was deleting rows, but the wrong rows, so I scrapped it. Tbh, I can't remember which function that one was.

Comment: There is nothing in the shown code or your post defining, or even hinting at, `x` and `y`.  How are those defined?

Comment: They are fixed, say rows 6 to 10. My apologies for that.

Comment: It looks like that should work. Have you tried simply looping through the rows you want to delete? Something like: [for i = x to y] [ws.rows(i).delete] [next i]

Comment: The issue with looping like that is that when you delete the row it'll shift upwards, meaning you start deleting the wrong rows. The correct approach with looping is simply to delete the same line *n* times where *n* is (last delete row) - (first delete row) + 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
ws.Rows("6:10").EntireRow.Delete
```

You can also define 6 and 10 as variables and then have something like

```
ws.Rows(x & ":" & y).EntireRow.Delete
```

Edit:

If this doesn't work, try:

```
wb.Sheets("sheet name").Range("A" & x & ":A" & y).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: If I want to do it for another worksheet, can I do it like wb.Sheets("Sheet3").Rows("6:10").EntireRow.Delete ?

Comment: Yep that would work as well. Really you can do this with any range object.

Comment: When I try it calling another sheet, I get a type mismatch error

Comment: What about trying wb.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A6:A10").EntireRow.Delete (?)